# Attribute directive accessing element and adding a listner

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I need to write an attribute directive using Angular 1.5.5 which is basically restricting inputs on keypress event of the text box. So it should look like this

```
<input type="number" name="age" id="age" restrict-char="['e','-']" />
```

How can we write an attribute directive **without using link function**. I dont want to use link function since i will be porting my code base to Angular 2.0 and link functions are not supported there.

Comment: Can't you just use `pattern` on input?

Comment: yea i tried that, ng-pattern does not work on keypress. Which means i will have to add an event listner to all text boxes whereever i need to restrict that input.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if that is what you want but you can use $parsers on ngModelController and set ng-model-options to update on any event.

```js
angular.module('app', []);

angular.module('app').directive('restrictChar', () => {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    require: 'ngModel',
    scope: {
      restricted: '=restrictChar'
    },
    controller: function ($scope, $element) {
      const ngModel = $element.controller('ngModel');
  
      ngModel.$parsers.unshift((value) => {
        const newVal = value
          .split('')
          .filter((char) => $scope.restricted.indexOf(char) === -1)
          .join('');
        
        $element.val(newVal);
        
        
        return newVal;
      });
    }
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app">
  <input type="text" ng-model="x" name="age" id="age" restrict-char="['e','-']" ng-model-options="{updateOn: 'keyup'}" /><br>
  {{x}}
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks alot for your answer, but i can still type in the '-' and 'e' in your code example, but i think you are close..very close

Comment: @ATHER it should be fine now